# Indexoutofrangeexception in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

```
struct Player
{
    public string Name;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
static Player[] players = new Player[amountofPlayers];

static void ResetGame() {
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!");
    Console.Write("How many player will be taking part today: ");
    string playerNo = Console.ReadLine();
    amountofPlayers = int.Parse(playerNo);
    if (amountofPlayers <= 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amountofPlayers; i = i + 1)
        {
            int displayNumber = i + 1;
            Console.Write("Please enter the name of player " + displayNumber + ": ");
            players[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); //error is here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of players less than 4!");
    }
}

static int amountofPlayers;
```

Comment: what is the value of amountofPlayers. its 0 so if players [2] will throw error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
static Player[] players = new Player[amountofPlayers];
```

is executing before you assign a value to `amountOfPlayers` based on the user input. So `amountOfPlayers` has its default value of 0, and you're creating an array of 0 elements.

I suggest you just declare the variable:

```
 static Player[] players;
```

then make `amountOfPlayers` a *local* variable in your `ResetGame` method, initializing the array after you've asked how many players there are:

```
static void ResetGame() {
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!");
    Console.Write("How many player will be taking part today: ");
    string playerNo = Console.ReadLine();
    int amountofPlayers = int.Parse(playerNo);
    players = new Player[amountOfPlayers];
    ...
}
```

I' *also* suggest making `Player` a class instead of a struct, keeping fields private, and using properties instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your array of players is initialized to 0 because it is static and at first your `numberofPlayers` is 0. You have to initialize it when you obtain number of players.

```
static Player[] players;
static int amountofPlayers;

static void ResetGame()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!");
    Console.Write("How many player will be taking part today: ");
    string playerNo = Console.ReadLine();
    amountofPlayers = int.Parse(playerNo);

    if (amountofPlayers <= 4)
    {
        players = new Player[amountofPlayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < amountofPlayers; i = i + 1)
        {
            int displayNumber = i + 1;
            Console.Write("Please enter the name of player " + displayNumber + ": ");
            players[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); //error is here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of players less than 4!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    struct Player
        {
            public string Name;
            public int X;
            public int Y;
        }
        static Player[] players = new Player[amountofPlayers];


        static void ResetGame() {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!");
            Console.Write("How many player will be taking part today: ");
            string playerNo = Console.ReadLine();
            amountofPlayers = int.Parse(playerNo);
         Array.Resize(ref  players, amountofPlayers ); /// this will resize your array element to the accepted amount of player
                if (amountofPlayers <= 4)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < amountofPlayers; i = i + 1)
                    {
                        int displayNumber = i + 1;
                        Console.Write("Please enter the name of player " + displayNumber + ": ");
                        players[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); //error is here
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of players less than 4!");
                }
        }

        static int amountofPlayers;
```

Answer (score 2):

`players` is initialised before `amountofPlayers` is set up (ie when `amountofPlayers` is still zero)

Seeing that you only want to allow up to 4 players set up, you might want to initialise `amountofPlayers` to 4:

`static int amountofPlayers = 4;`